# Trouble calling urlbuilder.Buildurl in my application

Tags: c#, winforms, url

I'm trying to let the user build a URL with a GUI from within my WinForms application.  I came across Urlbuilder.Buildurl.  It seems to provide what I need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154075%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
// Launch the Url Builder using the specified control
// parent, initial URL, empty relative base URL path,
// window caption, filter string and URLBuilderOptions value.
```

Unfortunately the sample provided doesn't even compile.

this.Component is an unknown member.

Has anyone used this and if so, any suggestions what I'm missing?

Should I just create my own dialog and use System.UriBuilder(...) ?

-- Edit --
This *is* in a form class.  I *do* have System.Design referenced according to the documentation.

this.Component is not a member of the Form class.

-- Edit --
This little bugger is the internal editor used by Visual Studio when you are selecting a URL, such as a Hyperlink URL or an Image URL within your project.  NOT what I wanted.  Time to build that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to compile you need to call it from with in form class.